# How to switch canvas in j2me

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui

I am developing a j2me application using canvas. In my application I have 3 canvas. I need to switch them regularly but sometimes I am facing problem either they don't switch or I got blank white screen

I use

```
display.setCurrent(maincanvas);
```

But still it's not working

Answer (score 1):

```
    Display.getDisplay(midlet).setCurrent(((MidletName)midlet).MethodName());
```

in canvas whenever you want to switch your canvas code, you type this line. And Create Mehod in midlet, after you create object canvas. For example:

```
Splash hitSplash;
private Canvas gameView=null;
startApp() {
    hitSplash= new CanvasClass(this);
    Display.getDisplay(this).setCurrent(hitSplash);
} 
public Canvas getMenu1() 
{
    if (gameView!=null) gameView = null;
    gameView =  new CrackerWindow(this,getSplash());
    System.gc();
    return gameView;
}
private Splash getSplash() 
{
    return hitSplash;
}
```